# How can I change the old url with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I made a new website with codeigniter for the existing website. How can I change the url structure of the old site to the new one?

For example:

The url on my new site:
[www.mydomain.com/lang/product/productname](http://www.mydomain.com/lang/product/productname)

I want to convert this to [www.mydomain.com/productname.html](http://www.mydomain.com/productname.html) with htaccess.

My current htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: URL rewriting is an already broadly discussed and well documented topic - so please show us what attempts you made so far, after making a proper effort to read up on it.

Comment: I tried what was written on stackoverflow, but in general it redirected from scratch. I already have directions. It goes to www.mydomain.com/lang/product/productname with existing redirects.
Is it possible to make new redirects on these redirects?

Comment: Each external redirect causes a new request by the client, so yes, sure - you can rewrite those again then, if you like. But not having _multiple_ redirects would of course be better, in terms of speed/user experience, and SEO as well.

Comment: It sounds like you want to actually change the new URL structure (as created with Codeigniter) back to the old URL structure? In other words no redirects at all, just the same old URL structure??

Comment: Yes, you are right. I want to revert to old url structure actually.

Comment: If you want to maintain the old URL structure then this is something you need to configure in CI itself, not `.htaccess`.